# Trading View has a Divergence Indicator that I'd like information how how to use the Alerts effectively

Tags: new-operator, flags, pine-script, indicator, alerts

I am not a coder.

I'd like to use the basic, locked, TView indicator Alerts to notifications when a Bull / Bear flag appears from the "Divergence Indicator". It doesn't have a script author to ask. Can this Alert be done with the script and coding that already exists? How?

If not, How much would it be to code something like this?

Comment: this is not a site for negotiating contracts or scoping projects. sorry. try upwork.com

Answer (score 0):

You can configure alerts using the indicator without any changes to it, provided you are happy with the possibilities it provides as is. Here, we have configured an alert on its `Regular Bullish` plot which shows a non-zero value when a bullish divergence occurs.

Use the Data Window and inspect bars, as we are doing here, to see which plots activate when your conditions occur.
[image]